# Symfony 4: Display dynamic value in modal

Tags: modal-dialog, symfony4

I want to display the details of an object (from Controller classe) in modal but after doing the code below i got this error:

> Variable "doaDetails" does not exist.

```
<a data-href="{{ path("details_dao", { 'id': dao.id } ) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#detailsModal" class="fas fa-info-circle fa-1x" title="Détails" style="color:white;"></a>
```

my modal in the view :

```
 <!-- Modal -->


<div  class="modal fade" id="detailsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" >
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" >
                <h5 class="modal-title">Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                    <div class="card" style="background:transparent;">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-ok collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    Détails
                                </button>
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                            <div class="card-body">


                                Nature :  {{ doaDetails.natureDAO}}<hr> 
                                Type :{{ doaDetails.typeDAO}}<hr>
                                Nom du Marché :  {{ doaDetails.nomMarche}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

My script after clicke on button:

> Détails of modal

```
$('#detailsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

action details in Controller class:

```
     /**
     * @Route("admin/dao/{id}/details_dao", name="details_dao")
     */
    public function detailsDAO(MarcheDAO $dao, MarcheDAORepository $repo ){
        $daoDetails= $repo->find($dao);
        return $this->render('admin/dao/liste_dao.html.twig', [
            'doaDetails'=>$daoDetails
        ]); 

    }
```

As you can see, the link is dynamic with the ID of the recod. Now, I want to open a modal with dynamic values for the details action. How I can do this.
Help!!